# What is use of requirejs-config.js in magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

I check many references about the use of requirejs-config.js but the actual use of this file is not cleared yet. If anyone is aware of it so please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader.
"requirejs-config.js" is the file in which we add all configurations. Just read the Magento doc below page you will get more clarity.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/requirejs.html

Answer (score 0):

RequireJS is a JavaScript file and module loader. It improves perceived page load times because it allows JavaScript to load in the background. In particular, it enables asynchronous JavaScript loading.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148985/use-require-config-js-to-load-files-needed-on-all-pages

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30561275)